# How to check direction of ViewPager immediatelly?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I am using ViewPager. I want to check direction of current ViewPager page whenever is page moving. It may be moved either by the user (swipe/ click on another tab in tab layout) or by ViewPager itself (user don't finish swipe and the page is moving back to idle position.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried bunch of different solution (f.e. calculating view direction with PageTransformer and so on.) but they usually doesn't work very well. You may get wrong direction if you are on first/last tab. You may not get any direction if the page is moved by viewpager itself instead of user's swipe ...

In the end there is really simple solution which is absolutely "bug-proof" :) .

```
new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                private float lastPositionAndOffsetSum = 0f;

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                    if (position + positionOffset == lastPositionAndOffsetSum) {
                       //IT'S NOT MOVING
                    } else if (position + positionOffset > lastPositionAndOffsetSum) {
                       //RIGHT TO LEFT
                    } else {
                       //LEFT TO RIGTH
                    }
                    lastPositionAndOffsetSum = position + positionOffset                    }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {}

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
            });
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Set setOnPageChangeListener to your ViewPager.

```
viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(
            new OnPageChangeListener(){
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
    if(lastPage>arg0)
      {//User Move to left}
    else(lastPage<arg0) 
     {//User Move to right}
      lastPage=arg0
}
});
```

Look at the onPageSelected(int position) method of ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener. The position gives the index of newly selected page. If you keep a track of the last page index, then you can compare it against the position of current page index you can get the left/right direction of viewpager.

Comment: That is not a solution for my problem. I need to get the direction immediately. This way I would get a direction too late. onPageSelected method is triggered only if the ViewPager is "sure" that the next page will be selected. It won't give you a direction i you move the page by f.e. 20px.